# Using heron library, proxy.cgi is responding incorrectly, activated via python on windows

Tags: python, cgi-bin, heron

When I try to get feature info for layer "derine500" the request is all good
`http://192.168.0.173:8000/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.173%3A8080%2Fgeoserver%2Fwms%3FLAYERS%3DProjekti%253Aderine500%26QUERY_LAYERS%3DProjekti%253Aderine500%26STYLES%3D%26SERVICE%3DWMS%26VERSION%3D1.1.1%26REQUEST%3DGetFeatureInfo%26BBOX%3D7468281%252C4723226%252C7526857%252C4759738%26FEATURE_COUNT%3D8%26HEIGHT%3D652%26WIDTH%3D1046%26FORMAT%3Dimage%252Fpng%26INFO_FORMAT%3Dapplication%252Fvnd.ogc.gml%26SRS%3DEPSG%253A7392%26X%3D609%26Y%3D213`

`url: http://192.168.0.173:8080/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=Projekti%3Aderine500&QUERY_LAYERS=Projekti%3Aderine500&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=7468281%2C4723226%2C7526857%2C4759738&FEATURE_COUNT=8&HEIGHT=652&WIDTH=1046&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fvnd.ogc.gml&SRS=EPSG%3A7392&X=609&Y=213`

but when I try to check the response it shows that `proxy.cgi` was not executed it gives me this
`proxy.cgi` is executed by

**startheron.py** which contains

`import os`
`import http.server`
`import socketserver`
`PORT = 8000`
`handler = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler`
`handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi-bin/"]`
`os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`
`handler.dont_inherit = True`
`with socketserver.TCPServer(("192.168.0.173", PORT), handler) as httpd:`
`print("Serving on port", PORT)`
`print("Open your web browser and navigate to http://192.168.0.173:8000")`
try:
   `httpd.serve_forever()`
 `except KeyboardInterrupt:`
  `print("\nServer interrupted. Exiting...")`

here is what `proxy.cgi` contains
`https://lib.heron-mc.org/heron/latest/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi`

can anyone help with this please!!!

1. I tried to activate `proxy.cgi` so that other function of exports format which works via `proxy.cgi` will be activated.